# Why $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] return 'index.php' when I use nginx rewrite?

Tags: php, nginx, yii

I am using YII Framework and everything is OK on Apache server, but it turn out wrong on Nginx. 
When I request URL www.test.com/index.php/a/b, the $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] return '/index.php' which is exactly is what I need, but when I request URL www.test.com/a/b which is rewrite to the same file named 'index.php',  $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] turn out to be 'index.php' which is different from Apache. My nginx conf is as following:

```
server {
    set $host_path "/data/yii/application";
    access_log  off;

    server_name www.yii.com;
    root   $host_path;
    set $yii_bootstrap "index.php";

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        index  index.html $yii_bootstrap;
        try_files $uri $uri/ $yii_bootstrap?$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(protected|framework|themes/\w+/views) {
        deny  all;
    }

    #avoid processing of calls to unexisting static files by yii
    location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;

        #let yii catch the calls to unexising PHP files
        set $fsn /$yii_bootstrap;
        if (-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name){
            set $fsn $fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9001;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fsn;

        #PATH_INFO and PATH_TRANSLATED can be omitted, but RFC 3875 specifies them for CGI
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fsn;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because nginx does things differently. Perhaps you should report a bug.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams
It's configured differently. It does things exactly how it was configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is wrong:

```
set $yii_bootstrap "index.php";

location / {
    index  index.html $yii_bootstrap;
    try_files $uri $uri/ $yii_bootstrap?$args;
}
```

It should be:

```
location / {
    index  index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$uri?$args;
}
```

See also: http://nginx.org/en/docs/faq/variables_in_config.html

--

And this part:

```
location ~ \.php {
    fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;

    #let yii catch the calls to unexising PHP files
    set $fsn /$yii_bootstrap;
    if (-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name){
        set $fsn $fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9001;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fsn;

    #PATH_INFO and PATH_TRANSLATED can be omitted, but RFC 3875 specifies them for CGI
    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fsn;
}
```

must be replaced with:

```
location ~ ^(?<script>.+\.php)(?<pathinfo>.*)$ {
    try_files $script =404;

    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9001;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$script;

    #PATH_INFO and PATH_TRANSLATED can be omitted, but RFC 3875 specifies them for CGI
    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $pathinfo;
    fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$script;
}
```

--

And you should avoid things like this:

```
set $host_path "/data/yii/application";
root   $host_path;
```

must be:

```
root /data/yii/application;
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/faq/variables_in_config.html